# Simple html dom - all tr except the first one

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to find all `<tr>` starting from the second, but i don't know how to get it right..

```
$items = $html->find('tr');
```

That piece of code gets all trs but i want everyone except the first one because that one contains `<th>`.

Answer (score 7):

Just cut off the first element.

```
$items = array_slice($html->find('tr'), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get your list with `$html->find('tr');` make a loop that don't care of the first "index/row".

Answer (score 1):

if Simple html dom work like Jquery, try to use like this:

```
$items = $html->find('tr:not(:has(th)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all trs from $html->find('tr'); from this u can add the condition to ignore the if the next element for object is "th" tag then u can ignore that tr.

Answer (score 0):

As PoulsQ suggests you CAN do it like

```
$firstTr = true;

foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
  if(!$firstTr) {
    // YOUR LOGIC FOR A TR HERE
  }
  else {
    $firstTr = false;
  }
}
```

But I think it would be nicer code if you query the DOM to ignore the first element.